# flutter buid apk command giving errors

Tags: flutter

hi ım trying to get an app file from flutter ım using a Mac and it isn't working proprley for me ı tried googling for the answer or a fix but nothing came up ı tried doing the things that the error told me to do but nothing seems to work for me [the error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UMtO.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make adjustments to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

You have to explicitly specify whether `android:exported` value in your `AndroidManifest.xml` is `"true"` or `"false"`

For example:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You can read more details about [android:exported here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported)

Comment: i tried both true and false but nothing changed any other potensial solutions